# RTK Query: Get one element from list depending on useGet...Query hook argument

Tags: typescript, api, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I fetch a list of articles in an external api using RTK Query like so (in createAPI) :

```js
getArticles: builder.query<{ data: ArticleDTO[] }, null>({
   query: () => "/api/v1/articles",
}),
```

It works great but now I need to get one single article and I don't have an endpoints to get one article.
I was thinking to use RTK Query transformResponse to return one element from the list but I can't access the given query argument so I don't know how do do it !

Don't hesitate to ask for precision !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would rather do that when you use the hook

```js
const result = useGetArticlesQuery(undefined, {
  selectFromResult: result => ({ ...result, data: result.data?.some.thing })
})
```

Of course you could also abstract that into a custom hook.

This way, you won't make the same request multiple times to get your value.

Comment: Seems great, I will give it a try !

Comment: That's seems to be the good answer. More details here : https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/queries#selecting-data-from-a-query-result

Comment: It's also explained as part of the Redux Essentials tutorial in one of the RTK Query chapters. Highly recommend reading, starting here for RTKQ: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-7-rtk-query-basics